# Angular 4 Safari - settings object without keyValue property defined

Tags: angular, safari, primeng

In Safari,

In primeng input text field, while typing into the text box I can see logged into the console errors of the form.

> handleKeypress — injected.entry.js:8231TypeError: undefined is not an
>   object (evaluating 'settings.keyValue.charCodeAt')

Essentially, it looks like the settings object is lacking some of the expected properties.
This happens as soon as type in the first character on the box.

This is the following javascript function of the injected.entry.js that breaks:

```
function handleKeypress(e) {
        var applyMeta = settings.useMetaKey ? e.metaKey : true;
        var applyShift = settings.useShiftKey ? e.shiftKey : true;
        var applyCtrl = settings.useCtrlKey ? e.ctrlKey : true;
        var applyAlt = settings.useAltKey ? e.altKey : true;
        var applyKey = settings.keyValue.charCodeAt(0) === e.keyCode;
        if (applyMeta && applyShift && applyCtrl && applyAlt && applyKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            getSelectedText();
        }
```

The line that is broken is the following:

```
var applyKey = settings.keyValue.charCodeAt(0) === e.keyCode;
```

This particular file, seems to be safari specific. In chrome, in the sources tab, at least, if I search "cmd + o" for the file, I do not find it.

In Safari, the URL for this file would be:
safari-extension://co.randompaper.safari.polyglot-58XDWHK3JX/295b5352/injected.entry.js

This URL is obtained by copy a link reference to the file.

The following code snippet illustrates the input text field where the issue takes place.

```
<input id="emailInput" pInputText type="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="eMail" name="eMail">
```

Is anyone aware of the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The issue I was experiencing on the web page was associated to a Safari extension called polyglot.

By checking Safari > Preferences > Extensions and disabling polyglot, the issue could be made to go away.

This issue seems to be correlated with the following open issue:
https://github.com/uetchy/Polyglot/issues/21

For the time being I am disabling the extension, it does not seem to be hurting me but the anoyance of being an error on every key press leads me to disable the extension.